# Web Share API doesn't work in iPhone when testing locally

Tags: javascript, ios, https, localhost, create-react-app

I'm trying to implement a share button that uses the Web Share API in a website that I'm developing using `create-react-app`.

I'm testing the website using Chrome on MacOS and Safari on iPhone.

Before implementing this, I used my iPhone to test the website. I could do this accessing the "On Your Network" link that `create-react-app` displayed after building.

```
You can now view blahblahblah in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.101:3000

Note that the development build is not optimised.
```

But I ran into problems when testing the Web Share API on the iPhone: I couldn't make the button work. After some investigation, I noticed that:

- iOS Safari would can run the Web Share button normally when accessing the deployed website (in a https address)
- iOS Safari would cannot run the Web Share button when accessed by the Network link.

Basically, I have this function that successfully share a link if run by the deployed website, but displays an alert if run by the Network link.

```js
const webShare = () => {
  if (navigator.share) {
    navigator
      .share({
        title: "web.dev",
        text: "Check out web.dev.",
        url: "https://web.dev/",
      })
      .then(() => console.log("Successful share"))
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error sharing", error));
  } else {
    alert("Share is not supported");
  }
};
```

I suspect that this has to do with the Network local link being http (**http**://10.0.0.101:3000) as the Web Share API can run only on secure contexts (**https**)

[image: Font: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share]

Not sure about how to proceed here, I wanted to test my website in my iPhone without having to deploy it every time. I searched a bit about "port forwarding in Chrome", but looks like it only works with Android devices (and I'm not sure I completely understand what port forwarding is - and if it would solve my problem in the first place

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/

Comment: @ChrisG This solves my problem, thanks! Now my browsers are complaining about invalid certificate, but I think I can search about that on my own now.

Comment: The certificate is probably a self-signed one, i.e. not suitable for production. Doesn't matter though, as long as you're now serving https and you can tell the browser to allow it. edit: I just checked the link and this is explained right there on the page: `Note that the server will use a self-signed certificate, so your web browser will almost definitely display a warning upon accessing the page.` They also tell you how to use a custom (i.e. valid) cert in the section directly below.